# Why does Outlook crash when trying to copy over calendar events from Facebook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, facebook

Sometimes I have events in Facebook that I choose to export. I save the .ics file and then open it which launches Outlook. The event shows up as a lone event in a new calendar.

When I open the event and then try to copy the event to my main Calendar in Exchange/Outlook, Outlook crashes.

Why does this happen, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you may be able to stop it happening by not doing that.

I am guessing that you use your Exchange account as your primary email and calendar.  If you do not use the local .pst file at all, it would be neater to get rid of it.  At least, make your primary account the default for calendar.

Close Outlook.  Open Control Panel and type Mail in the search box.  In that dialogue, press Data Files and go to the Data Files tab and make your Exchange account the default.

You can also delete any unused data files and mailboxes there.

Comment: Exchange is my primary calendar. A second calendar only appears when I open the .ics export file from Facebook.